# What is the statement to go from one ViewController to another ViewController AFTER I have selected an item from my UIPickerView?

Tags: xcode, select, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

I have an initial view controller. It goes to the next view controller which has the “picker wheel” in it. From that screen, if the user selects one of the 4 items in the picker wheel and stops on it. Then press ONE action button to initiate several C code statements.

I need specific help with coding the statement (s) that cause the transition from one view controller to another view controller.

I’m thinking out loud, it should look something like this (but I really don’t know):

```
‘If row = 0 then go to View controller B.’
‘If row = 1 then go to View controller C’
```

etc.

Or use some other ‘VERY SIMPLE’ method for transitioning from a ‘selection from a picker wheel to another view controller’.

**Basic documentation.**

I have 4 viewcontrollers :

1. First view controller is named - VCa
2. Second view controller is named - VC1
3. Third View controller is named - VCb
4. Forth view controller is named - Vcc

There is nothing but the default 'Storyboard" coding in this VCa (view controller).

The first view controller only has a label named VCa , so we can see which VC this is.

And it has a button named Button A, so I can do a modal segue to the next view controller named VC1.

The second view controller (VC1) only has some basic things.

- The picker wheel named `pickerView1`. The array named `Companies` with data.
- A button to go back to the first view controller VCa.
- The button is named `B1Back`.
- A button to go forward to the next view controller named VCb.
  The pupose for this button is only for demo. purposes to transition to VCb.
  It has nothing to do with coding a solution to allow the picker wheel selection to . transition somehow to the next view controller.
  The button is named `B1forwardtob`.
- The same is true for the 3rd button. It just allows this VC (VCa) to transition to . . another view controller named VCc. The button is named B1forwardtoc.
- An ACTION button that does nothing, yet. I’m hoping the transition from view controller to view controller code goes here (after the action button). But again I don’t know what I don’t know.

There is nothing but the default 'Storyboard" coding in this VCb (view controller).
The third viewcontroller (VCb) is very simple too. It is there just to go to and then go back to VC1.

There is nothing but the default 'Storyboard" coding in this VCc (view controller).
Same for the forth viewcontroller (VCc). It is there just to go to and then go backto VC1.

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of hard to tell what you're asking, but are you looking for something like this?

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    UIViewController *viewControllerToDisplay;

    if (row == 0) {
        viewControllerToDisplay = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
    } else if (row == 1) {
        viewControllerToDisplay = [[ViewControllerC alloc] init];
    }

    if (viewControllerToDisplay) {
        [self presentViewController:viewControllerToDisplay animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```